# How to isolate $\,\alpha\,$ given $\,A\!\cdot\!\sin(\alpha) + B\!\cdot\!\cos(\alpha) = C$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I encountered this problem while trying to generate a truncated cone tangent to a sphere given the sphere's radius, the minor perimeter's radius, and the distance between center points. Isolating this angle is useful as it will tell me the second radius and distance in one variable. I have attempted to isolate α using the following equation:

$\alpha=\arctan\left(\dfrac CB\right)-\arccos\left(\!\!\dfrac A{\sqrt{C^2 + B^2}}\!\!\right)$

This equation was derived geometrically, but it does not work in practice. Changing the form to account for possible gaps in the domain has not worked, so I'm assuming my methodology is flawed.

Please let me know if there is any need for clarification.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\theta$ be an angle such that $\cos(\theta) = A/\sqrt{A^2+B^2}$ and $\sin(\theta) = B/\sqrt{A^2+B^2}$ (so if $B \ge 0$ you can use $\theta = \arccos(A/\sqrt{A^2+B^2}$, but if $B < 0$ you'll want $-$ that).  Then your equation says
$\sin(\alpha+\theta) = C/\sqrt{A^2+B^2}$. Can you continue?

Comment: This would then allow for isolating + by taking the arcsin of the new equation - subtracting the identity for  then isolates . Is that correct?